# Spring Batch Couchbase Reader

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, couchbase

I am trying to read some data from Couchbase. But I do not see much information about having a couchbase reader. I am thinking about writing some custom reader so tried using RepositoryItemReader, but that also does not seem to work.
My question is is there a reason that Couchbase is not supported out of the box in Spring Batch?

Answer (score 0):

No particular reason. There is an open feature request for that: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1330. Feel free to vote.

Contributions are welcome!